# Backbone.js render performance and repaints

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm building a backbone.js application. It has quite a few interactive calculator type forms. I need values in these forms to update live when users type values into inputs. I was thinking two approaches:

**Strategies:**

1) rerender the view upon each interaction using underscore templates

OR

2) render once, find every point of display in jQuery and update them on each interaction

**My question:** What do you think is best practice both from a maintainability point of view and from a browser performance standpoint. Minimizing repaints etc seems like a good idea to me but attaching all those listeners and pairing them to bits of the view also seems a bit yuck.

Any advice greatly appreciated,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is certainly a bit subjective question and can not be answered either way. It really depends upon the complexity of both the strategies which again depend on your app logic. Still here are a few thoughts:

- You can have multiple elements sitting parallel to each other and each element has its own content (view). Depending upon logic, hide the rest of them and show only one. This avoids re-rendering of the view multiple times but yes you have to write some logic of maintaining multiple views (Hide all, show one). So this approach is fine as long as you have 2-3 views and your app needs switching between these views multiple times.
- Re-painting a view may not be a costly operation depending upon how you do it. Just cache the selector and do all the changes in it and update the DOM only once which is the most common practice. So you are good if you are re-rendering a view again if it costs only one DOM operation.

From code maintainability perspective, definitely go with Strategy #1, Re-rendering of view.

Comment: I am glad if it helps you. In initial stages, I used to carry the burden of same doubt but as I made my hands more dirty..things became more clear :)